# How to create a random sample from .csv in r

Tags: r, random

I need to pull a random sample of 100,000 - 200,000 rows from a csv dataset of 2.8mil rows. How do I effectively do this so that the random sample can be cleaned and processed?

Under the `DMwR2` library, I have used the `sampleCSV` function, but the output data messes up the 22 variables that I need to use.

```
library(caret)

library(DMwR2)
```

dataset source: https://www.kaggle.com/pschale/mlb-pitch-data-20152018#pitches.csv

```
pitchData <- sampleCSV(file.choose(), 200000, 2867154 , header = TRUE , mxPerc = 0.5)

summary(pitchData)
```

I expect the output of `summary(pitchData)` to have the same variable names as the csv file, but it renames them using random numbers, and some of the variables are lost.

Comment: Why not use sample function in combination with set.seed?

Comment: I didn't think sample function would work for a large csv file. Ideally, I won't have to load the entire file each time I run.

Comment: > set.seed(12)
> sample = sample(cleanPitch, 100000, replace = FALSE,)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following function can do what the question asks for. Note that it uses a function from package `R.utils`.

The return values is a list with 2 members:

1. `lines` the line numbers read in;
2. `data` the data frame.

This can be changed to return just the dataframe.

```
sample_csv <- function(fname, n, sep = ",", header = TRUE, ...){
  N <- R.utils::countLines(fname)
  stopifnot(N >= n)
  lns <- sample(N, n)
  x <- sapply(lns, function(l){
    scan(fname, what = character(), skip = l - 1, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE)
  })
  list(lines = lns,
       data = read.table(textConnection(x), 
                         sep = sep, header = header, ...)
  )
}

set.seed(1234)
res <- sample_csv(filename, 100, header = FALSE)
str(res$data)
```